# Carousel Blue Underline

Tags: css, carousel, slideshow

I have some trouble with bootstrap carousel. I cannot remove blue under lines.

[image: 1]

Can someone help me? It's not text decoration (`text-decoration: none;` doesn't work).

```
.carousel {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-decoration: none !important
}
.carousel-inner,.carousel,.carousel-indicators {
    text-decoration: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -150px;
    text-decoration: none !important
}
.section1-text {
    line-height: 1.55;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none !important
 
}

.section1-text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px ;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems like it depends on some other code too. Please create a demo out of your entire current code.

Comment: You probably have other css that is setting `text-decoration: underline` on your text. Check with browser inspector if there is any and overwrite that rule in your css.